# Expressjs mongodb update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In condition books.update({"id": {$eq: bid}}, {$set:{"status": login}}...
when i use variable bid it doesnt work but if i put  smth like books.update({"id": {$eq: 1}}, {$set:{"status": login}} it works just fine. I have to use variable in my project.

node code

```
app.get("/logged/:login/borrow/:bid/confirm", function(req,res){
  var login = req.params.login;
  var bid = req.params.bid;
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Nawiązano połączenie z serwerem");
  var books = db.collection('books');
      books.update({"id": {$eq: bid}}, {$set:{"status": login}}, function(er, result){
      assert.equal(er, null);
      res.redirect('/logged/'+login+'/borrow');
      });
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Pasting hjs file in case

```
  <a href="/logged/{{nick}}/return/{{id}}/confirm"></a>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that id is a numeric value, since the query with a 1 works.

Request parameters are strings. Convert the string to an integer and you should be fine.

```
var bid = parseInt(req.params.bid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `req.params.bid` is giving you a string number hence it's not matching. id field might be looking for 1 but you would be sending "1" in variable bid.

try to convert bid into a number and then check.

```
bid = parseInt(bid,10);
```